# Simple plugin to read json?

Tags: plugin, json, feed

I've been using [Phil Sturgeon's Rest](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/rest) to read in JSON data from a url but it looks like it's starting to fail, as it hasn't been updated for a while.
I just want to pull in a JSON feed and display the contents in a table with some re-formatting of the presentation of dates etc.
This is the template code I'm currently using:

```
{exp:rest url="https://www.britishorienteering.org.uk/fixturesjson.php?club=elo" verb="get" format="json" limit="5" parse="inward" cache="yes" refresh="180"}
<tr>
    <td>{exp:low_nice_date date="{date}" format="%D %M %d%S" localize="yes"}</td>
    <td><a href="{link}" target="_blank" title="More info about {title} - opens in a new tab">{title} - {venue}</a></td>
    <td>{nearest_town}</td>
    <td>{level}</td>
</tr>
{/exp:rest}
```

I can't find anything on Devotee that does this, any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered writing your own plugin, or modifying the current one to make it functional? Grabbing JSON is pretty trivial in most cases (if you have something more complex going, please add some details).

Comment: I've never written a plugin and have limited php skills, I can often make minor adaptions to  something existing but need the core to be there. So if there was a plugin for this and it was just a matter of editing the the data field names etc. I could handle that.